# dyld: Library not loaded error on Eclipse Nsight on Mac

Tags: eclipse, cuda, nvcc, dyld, nsight

I've installed Cuda 5.0 (Preproduction Release) on my iMac which has an NVIDIA GeForce 9400 Cuda-enabled GPU. Using the bundled Eclipse Nsight, I created a project and built it successfully. But, when I try to run it, Eclipse shows me this error message:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libcudart.dylib   Referenced from:
>   /Users/home/cuda-workspace/sample_project/Release/sample_project
>   Reason: image not found

Any help?

Comment: The production release of CUDA 5.0 has been available for a while now. I would uninstall and try again with the production release.

Comment: In the getting started guide it says:

Comment: Define the environment variables.
The PATH variable needs to include /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-5.0/bin.
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH needs to contain /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-5.0/lib.
The typical way to place these values in your environment is with the following commands:
export PATH=/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-5.0/bin:$PATH
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-5.0/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
To make these settings permanent, place them in ~/.bash_profile.

Comment: Please bear with me, I'm a newbie, and I'm not sure how to set these variables permanently ..

Comment: It depends on which shell you're using. If you're using bash, add the settings in your ~/.bashrc file. I usually add such settings close to the top, just after the line that checks for an interactive session.

Answer (score 1):

1. Please use the production release of the CUDA SDK.
2. Note that Nsight should be ran from the shell, it does not work when double-clicking the application bundle from the finder.

This is the shell script that starts Nsight in 5.0 production release:

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda-5.0/bin LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib:/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64 UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0 /usr/local/cuda-5.0/libnsight/nsight $@
```